# Frequent Proxmox server interruptions in Hetzner

Tags: proxmox, hetzner

Unfortunately, there is a problem with server access at hetzner datacenter for some time. When we connect to the server with a KVM, we find that the server has not crashed, as if the server's network card is hanging. The installed operating system is Proxmox 5. Also included is the EX61 NVMe server.

The following logs are logged at the kernel level:
e1000e 0000: 00: 1f.6 enp0s31f6: Detected Hardware Unit Hang:

For the above error, we used the following command:

```
/sbin/ethtool -K enp3s0 tx off rx off sg off tso off gro off
```

For the second way, we disable the `pcie_aspm` at the grub level of the operating system.
And finally, we decided to disable `C1E` in the BIOS.
Unfortunately, none of the above solutions resolved the problem.
Thanks if anyone has a previous experience in this field and helps me.

Answer (score 0):

What version of PVE packages you are using?
This issue has been fixed since +pve-kernel-4.12.
Try to Upgrade your kernel and pve-manager, If you have a subscription just run `apt-update && apt dist-upgrade -y`.
In case you don't have any subscription, Try to add non-enterprise repository into your system.